# Geographic location in Solidity

Tags: dapps, solidity-0.5.x

Does solidity have a way of fetching a persons geographic location(using something like msg.sender)?

Im building a dApp for national elections, and would need to verify the geographic location before doing the same.

Im a little new to solidity. Pls help.

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Comment: why Is geographical location important for this application? People living outside their origing country still can vote. I think the important part is how the keys are assigned to the voters. Once the keys are given (following a validation of the voter, before the elections) shouldn't be important where they are, as long as they prove their identity or right to vote with their private key, all is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethereum itself does not have that. It probably never will.

You might want to look at FOAM either for inspiration at the application layer or for a deeper understanding of how to approach such an issue. https://steemit.com/ethereum/@protegeaa/foambridgingethereumtotherealworld-8chacpi9xq

You could also consider a touch at a checkpoint and a maximum separation in time between events. For example, if one acquires a time-limited ballot from an entry point/gate or a witness/official/staff. Interactions with physical controls might be practical.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Rob's FOAM answer.

If you're expecting IP address* - and therefore `msg.sender` (glossing over how this would actually work... ) - to map to geographic location in an accurate and reliable way, then this is what one of the more vocal Tor devs has to say: "[GeoIP is Bullshit](https://github.com/epidemics-scepticism/writing/blob/master/misconception.md#geoip-is-bullshit)"

See also: "[A suprising amount of people want to be in North Korea](https://blog.benjojo.co.uk/post/north-korea-dprk-bgp-geoip-fruad)".

[*You didn't actually state this, but I'm assuming it's in there somewhere.]